# Detect if network is idle in Python

Tags: python, networking

I am making a Python based downloader. I have a working multiprocessing based console script as of now. I would like to know how to detect if the network is idle. That is, the users not using the network themselves (browsing, surfing, etc).

It should be able to do two things in this regard:

1. Resume downloading when network is detected idle.
2. Pause downloading when it detects some network activity.

One way to define 'idle-ness' could be to trigger if the network activity is at 1% of max bandwidth for 5 minutes straight.

Is there a better way to detect if network is idle?

Comment: `ifconfig eth0` which would give you rx and tx bytes and if run at regular intervals could give you a simple metric. I would wrap the command in pexpect (or similar) and examine the output. However I too would be interested in a proper way to do this.

Comment: The issue with this approach is that I can't know which process is taking how much network. I would like to know this to figure out if a browser or other action is causing network traffic and not my own downloader.

Comment: @MyPreciousss That is a really difficult application to develop, I have done that before but you have to access each operating system's kernel and retrieve network stats per process. I will get into specifics later on when I post my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the `psutil.network_io_counters` module:

> Return network I/O statistics as a namedtuple including the following
>   attributes:
>
> - bytes_sent:   number of bytes sent
> - bytes_recv:   number of bytes received
> - packets_sent: number of packets sent
> - packets_recv: number of packets received
> - errin:        total number of errors while receiving
> - errout:       total number of errors while sending
> - dropin:       total number of incoming packets which were dropped
> - dropout:      total number of outgoing packets which were dropped
>                  (always 0 on OSX and BSD)
>
> If pernic is True return the same information for every network
>   interface installed on the system as a dictionary with network
>   interface names as the keys and the namedtuple described above as the
>   values.

```
In [1]: import psutil
In [2]: psutil.network_io_counters(pernic=True)
Out[2]:
{'en0': iostat(bytes_sent=143391435L, bytes_recv=1541801914L,
               packets_sent=827983L, packets_recv=1234558L, errin=0L, errout=0L,
               dropin=0L, dropout=0),
 'gif0': iostat(bytes_sent=0L, bytes_recv=0L, packets_sent=0L, packets_recv=0L,
                errin=0L, errout=0L, dropin=0L, dropout=0),
 'lo0': iostat(bytes_sent=6143860L, bytes_recv=6143860L, packets_sent=55671L,
               packets_recv=55671L, errin=0L, errout=0L, dropin=0L, dropout=0),
 'p2p0': iostat(bytes_sent=0L, bytes_recv=0L, packets_sent=0L, packets_recv=0L,
                errin=0L, errout=0L, dropin=0L, dropout=0),
 'stf0': iostat(bytes_sent=0L, bytes_recv=0L, packets_sent=0L, packets_recv=0L,
                errin=0L, errout=0L, dropin=0L, dropout=0)
}
```

You can keep track of the sent and received bytes on the interface you want to monitor and that will give you information if the network is idle or busy.

Comment: How can I detect which process is taking how much? To be truly non-intrusive to the user's network use, I need to be able to detect if the bandwidth is from some other process or my own downloader.

Comment: On linux systems you can check the `/proc/PID/net/dev` and you also have a [bwmon](http://thp.io/2010/bwmon/). I know that mac has nettop, but I don't know how to do this on a BSD system.

Comment: Or you could use iptables to mark the packages depending on the source/port/destination etc.

Comment: I'll try this out and then follow up. If it works out, I'll mark it as resolved too. Thanks! @viktor kerkez

Answer (score 1):

I'm kind of wondering if this is the right approach at all. You will have to average over some time and check very often, and you will still have [TOCTTOU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use) problems (That is, just at exactly the same time you decide to start your next download segment, the user clicks on something that starts network activity).

A better approach may actually be to simply throttle (to a user-configurable level?) the download bandwidth of your application, so it only downloads at X KB/s. Yes, it will be a bit slower, but it will be much easier to implement, and much easier to understand how it works.